# Mongodb, mongoose product filter search query when user select's a filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am working on a product filter search on a mongodb database. I am using a node application with mongoose as the ORM to query mongodb and I am a newbie to mongodb.

Example document from a collection named job.

```
{
    "id": "123123123",
    "designation": "Full Stack Developer",
    "cities": [
        "Gurgaon",
        "Delhi",
        "Goa"
    ],
    "matchDetails": [
        "More than a million unique users on its website",
        "Crossed more than 4 lakh mobile app downloads",
        "You have (1) skills required for this job.",
        "Requires only 5 days a week",
        "Exceeds your salary expectations",
        "Perfect experience level",
        "Work in your current functional area"
    ],
    "currency": "Rupees",
    "benefits": [
        "5 day work week",
        "Flexible work hours",
        "Health care benefits"
    ],
}
```

Output after query:

```
{
    cities:[],
    matchDetails:[],
    benefits: [],
    currency: []
}
```

Note that above output is returned after we apply the query and **result is used to display filters** in the front-end not the actual product catalog.

I want to show filters on the job catalog page in a front-end application for the fields: cities, matchDetails, benefits, currency.

Upon choosing any combination of filter options there should not be any empty job catalog result set.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Use [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) - you can conditionally add filter in the aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Aggregation` query shown below:

```
db.job.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      designation: 1,
      currency: 1,
      cities: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$cities",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "Goa",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      matchDetails: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$matchDetails",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$this",
              [
                "Work in your current functional area",
                "You have (1) skills required for this job."
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      benefits: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$benefits",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "Flexible work hours",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2aBgG_uEV8p)